# How to install SQLPSX 1.6?

Tags: sql, powershell

Iam using Powershell 1.0 on my machine, so i want to install SQLPSX 1.6 for ease of manipulating SQL server , in [powershell 1.6](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/releases/view/32293)

I don't know how to install. I've tried running .\LibrarySMO.ps1, but nothing happened

Can you show me how to install ?

My machine is Windows XP ,Powershell 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in the directory where LibrarySMO.ps1 is located, you need to dot source the script which loads all of the functions for the Powershell session:

*dot  dot forward slash file name:*

**. .\LibrarySMO.ps1**

Comment: Thanks you so much, but how to add it,so each time it will reload automaically when i start new powershell console  ?

Comment: Add it your profile <root drive>\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1. If the file doesn't exist create it. See help about_Profiles for more information.

Comment: One last concern is when i use get-command, it doesn't list all new sql functions ,thought they have been loaded. How to show them by using get-command ? Iam new to Powershell.

Comment: In V1 you do get-command *-sql* or dir function:\*-sql*,  In V2/V3 it is a module, so this would be a better way in V2/V3: get-command -module sqlserver